# removing "which is" in this sentence

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to remove "which is" in this sentence?

> Our method is implemented on Ubuntu LTS operating system *(which is)*
>   running on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can omit "which is" in this technical context, for example:

> Android is a Java virtual machine running on the Linux kernel.

However, I think your sentence requires the definite article before the name Ubuntu, because by including the words "operating system" you need to set it apart from other operating systems. You will notice that in my example I have used an article before 'Java' because I've referred to it as a virtual machine; likewise, I've used an article before 'Linux' because I'm referring to it as a kernel. Your sentence should ideally be::

> Our method is implemented on the Ubuntu LTS operating system running on a virtual machine.

If you think your audience is perfectly aware of what Ubuntu is then there is really no need to tell them it is an operating system, and you could simply say:

> Our method is implemented on Ubuntu LTS running on a virtual machine.

Comment: In case I remove the "operating system" should I also omit "the" before *ubuntu*?

Comment: @Pablo Yes, same as my final example.

Comment: @Astralbee Can I use this reduction for this phrase: `"Each server which is used to host a website has different hardware."` to `"Each server used to host a website has different hardware."` (passive)?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Yes, the reduction is fine. In fact, the original sentence is wrong to use "which" - it should use "that".

Comment: @Astralbee, that is a half-truth invented by the Fowlers, and I'm certain you know as much. "That" is incorrect in a nonrestrictive clause, and no native makes the mistake. But restrictive "which" is abundantly attested by huge swathes of writers and speakers, particularly the British. I personally adhere to the guideline (because I worshipped Fowler as a 20-year-old) but it is dishonest to call it more than a recommendation.